# Merging two DataFrames using column names of one of the DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Task Description**

I have a bunch of DataFrames I read in from sheets in an xlsx file. Is it possible to merge `df` into `df2` and create a column in `df2` which is the sheet name stored in the loop.

I read the `df` in as follows:

```
for idx, sheet_name in enumerate(excel_file.sheet_names):
    df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name)

    # do some stuff
```

I wish to merge `df` with `df2` within this loop.

If we just do it for an individual sheet, for example, `revenue`, is it possible to create `df3`?

`df`

```
 Date            AR        AU      GB       US
1983-03-31     0.001   0.053206  0.001  0.160159
1983-04-30     0.001   0.053206  0.001  0.160159
1983-05-31     0.001   0.053206  0.001  0.160159
```

`df2`

```
 Date.        a   ...  z   loc     
1983-03-31                  AR
1983-03-31                  AU
1983-03-31                  GB
1983-03-31                  US
1983-04-30                  AR
1983-04-30                  AU
1983-04-30                  GB
1983-04-30                  US
1983-05-31                  AR
1983-05-31                  AU
1983-05-31                  GB 
1983-05-31                  US
```

**Desired DataFrame**
`df3`

```
 Date.        a   ...  z   loc   revenue 
1983-03-31                  AR   0.001
1983-03-31                  AU   0.053206
1983-03-31                  GB   0.001
1983-03-31                  US   0.160159
1983-04-30                  AR   0.001
1983-04-30                  AU   0.053206
1983-04-30                  GB   0.001
1983-04-30                  US   0.160159
1983-05-31                  AR   0.001
1983-05-31                  AU   0.053206
1983-05-31                  GB   0.001
1983-05-31                  US   0.160159
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['revenue'] = df.set_index('Date').lookup(df2['Date'], df2['loc'])
print(df3)
```

If there are missing value in `df` for any `'Date' , 'loc'` in df2:

```
df3 = (df.melt('Date', var_name = 'loc', value_name='revenue')
         .merge(df2, on=['Date' , 'loc'], how='right'))


print(df3)
```

---

**Output**

```
          Date loc   revenue
0   1983-03-31  AR  0.001000
1   1983-03-31  AU  0.053206
2   1983-03-31  GB  0.001000
3   1983-03-31  US  0.160159
4   1983-04-30  AR  0.001000
5   1983-04-30  AU  0.053206
6   1983-04-30  GB  0.001000
7   1983-04-30  US  0.160159
8   1983-05-31  AR  0.001000
9   1983-05-31  AU  0.053206
10  1983-05-31  GB  0.001000
11  1983-05-31  US  0.160159
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way out, melt `df` and merge with `df`.

```
 df3= print(df2.merge(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], \
                  var_name='loc', value_name='Revenue'),how='left', on=['Date','loc']))

print(df3)

     Date loc   Revenue
0   1983-03-31  AR  0.001000
1   1983-03-31  AU  0.053206
2   1983-03-31  GB  0.001000
3   1983-03-31  US  0.160159
4   1983-04-30  AR  0.001000
5   1983-04-30  AU  0.053206
6   1983-04-30  GB  0.001000
7   1983-04-30  US  0.160159
8   1983-05-31  AR  0.001000
9   1983-05-31  AU  0.053206
10  1983-05-31  GB  0.001000
11  1983-05-31  US  0.160159
```

Comment: I would accept @ansev answer. Mine basically a replica of his second. Some nice code there